# Invalid type error on Creating custom sObject in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am getting this error while creating a custom sObject. I was just trying this code in developer console.

**Error:** Invalid type: Restaurants_c

**Code:**

```
Restaurants_c res = new Restaurants_c();

res.Name = 'Shabana Bekari';

insert res;

system.debug(res);
```

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening ? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo (or copied it from a system that tries to be "helpful" and thinks you want *italics* when you use underscores)

There will never be `Restaurants_c`. Custom objects will have double underscore. Try with `Restaurants__c`

Comment: I have tried with _c and __c but it still doesn't work. I have been creating the custom objects from SETUP -> Object manager now as i am unable to do it using code.

Comment: Check what's the actual API name of the object in Setup -> Object Manager (in lightning) or Setup -> Create (in classic ui). Is it really a custom object? Maybe your company renamed Account to Restaurant? In that case the api name is still Account, code doesn't care about UI labels

Comment: No I am trying to create custom objects and no mater what name I use it doesn't work. The API name will only be generated once the custom object is created right.? Since I am a beginner please correct me if I am wrong.